# Android Studio Add an action button to the status bar

Tags: android, statusbar

There are a lot of buttons in the status bar (Wifi, Bluetooth, etc), how can I add a button there which will be connected to a function in my code so when the user press the button the function will get called? (Even if the app isn't open) [Image of the buttons that I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0HTC.jpg)

Comment: Those are called [Quick Setting Tiles](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TileService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/quicksettings/TileService#summary) to add a custom Quick Setting tile of your app.

Add this code in the Manifest file : (make sure you put your label and icon in the code)

```
<service
    android:name=".MyQSTileService"
    android:label="@string/my_default_tile_label"
    android:icon="@drawable/my_default_icon_label"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_QUICK_SETTINGS_TILE">
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.service.quicksettings.action.QS_TILE" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And create a  **MyQSTileService.java** class which extends TileService:
You can override various methods of the TileService class to perform actions at various events. Here I just overrode the onClick method which will be called when your qs tile is clicked.

```java
public class MyTileService extends TileService {

    @Override
    public void onClick() {
        // Perform your action here
        super.onClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to ask a question to owner of this answer how did you learn about TileService was there a course for everything in android or did you read all the documentation because it is a very deep and specific topic can you give some advice about learning deep and detail topics?i am interested in android development for 1 year but how can i improve myself faster like you?

Comment: I just read android documentations. documentation got everything and you can get some example code on the net to get a better idea of how things works.